# Upgrading Cordova Framework

Tags: iphone, cordova, upgrade

I was having the same issue with respect to receiving an error code 4 when trying to add a contact on my device running on iOS 6.1 (although it worked on the simulators). In reading a similar post ([Phonegap ContactError when saving contact on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022482/phonegap-contacterror-when-saving-contact-on-ios-6)) I saw that you should update the Cordova framework to 2.0+ to accomodate for iOS 6.  I updated Xcode to 4.6, but was not sure how to go about upgrading Cordova (or updating its integration withing XCode).  I'm currently running on version 1.7.0 for cordova and downloaded the 2.5 release. Is the upgrade incremental or can I make a version jump? Can anyone guide me on how to go about upgrading my Cordova framework version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, please do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From Cordova 1.7 to Cordova 2.5, there are no migration path. I would recommend to:

1. Backup your full mac os system
2. Uninstall Cordova 1.7
3. Install Cordova 2.5
4. Create a new XCode project according the 2.5 cordova tutorial
5. Copy and paste your html5 code from your old to your new project
6. Fix the issues

It is painful, but it is a clean migration path.